# Gradle 4+ can't resolve snapshots dependency from custom Maven repositories

Tags: gradle

In `build.gradle`, we can declare multiple repositories, including custom Maven repositories. In my case, I use two custom Maven repositories: one for releases, one for snapshots. And one `mavenCentral` repository. e.g.:

```
repositories {
maven {
    url 'http://xxxx:8080/repository/internal'
}
maven {
    url 'http://xxxx:8080/repository/snapshots'
}
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'xxxx:xxxx:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

`Gradle` 2.x can resolve the `SNAPSHOT` lib from  http://xxxx:8080/repository/snapshots. But, `Gradle` 4.x and 5.x can not resolve the `SNAPSHOT` lib.

From the https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html , I don't see any special requirements for using multiple repositories, not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have artifacts present in the first repository, Gradle will ignore the second one in Gradle 4.x. I do not remember the exact behaviour in Gradle 2.x but it might very well be different indeed.

One way to work around that issue, assuming the second repo never contains release artifacts would be to switch the order of repositories. Another solution would be to clean all snapshots from the `internal` one.

If this answer does not help, please provide more context, like the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried your suggestion but it does work.  If I put snapshot first, then it ends up can't find out any release lib located in internal repository.

Comment: And if this is the case, then does that means we should not include multiple repositories in build.gradle ? This does not sound right.

Answer (score 0):

```
14:17:50: Executing task 'build'...
```

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

  > Could not resolve com.xxx.yyy:lpp-interface:1.0.23.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :
  >   Could not resolve com.xxx.yyy:lpp-interface:1.0.23.
  >   Could not get resource 'http://xxx-mirror-maven:8080/repository/snapshots/com/xxx/yyy/lpp-interface/1.0.23/lpp-interface-1.0.23.pom'.
  >   Could not HEAD 'http://xxx-mirror-maven:8080/repository/snapshots/com/xxx/yyy/lpp-interface/1.0.23/lpp-interface-1.0.23.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Unable to fetch artifact resource.

Comment: some log for reference